# Serentity booksellers project

Tags: c++

In this part of the project, I store books and in this code, I am trying to sort the books based on the qty. The highest qty will be on the top and the lowest on the bottom. I have no compiler errors but when I run the program, the correct output isn't shown. Actually, no books are shown when I run this code. This is c++ coding.

````
  BookData book;
  fstream bookDataFile;
  int* qtyPtr[size];
  int min, temp, hold,index[size],qty[size];
  string key;
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  tm* tPtr = localtime(&t);
  cout<<"Quantity Listing\n";
  cout<<"Today's Date: "<<(tPtr->tm_mon)+1<<"-"<< (tPtr->tm_mday) <<"-"<< (tPtr\
->tm_year)+1900<< endl;

  cout<<"Title "<<"\t"<<"ISBN "<<"\t"<<"Quantity On Hand\n";
  cout<<"____________________________________________________________________\n\
";
  // bookDataFile.open("info.dat", ios::out|ios::in | ios::binary);
  // bookDataFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&book), sizeof(book));
  while(!bookDataFile.eof()){
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    qty[i] = book.getQty();
  }
  for(int i = 0; i<(size-1); i++){
    min = i;
    for(int j= i+1; j<size; j++){
      if(qty[j] > qty[min])
        min = j;
    }
    temp = qty[i];
    qty[i] = qty[min];
    qty[min] = temp;

    hold = index[i];
    index[i] = index[min];
    index[min] = hold;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    qtyPtr[i] = &qty[i];
  }

  for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
    if(strlen(book.getTitle().c_str()) == 0){
      break;
    }
    else{
      cout<<book.getTitle()<<setw(8)<<book.getISBN()<<setw(8)<< *qtyPtr<<"\n";}

   bookDataFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&book), sizeof(book));
  }
  }
   cout << "Press any key to continue: \n";
   // getline(cin,key);
   bookDataFile.close();
   return;

}```
This is what it should look like:
```Quantity Listing
Today's Date: 4-23-2020
Title   ISBN    Quantity On Hand
____________________________________________________________________
2       2       2
1       1       1
Press any key to continue: ```

This is what it looks like now:
```Quantity Listing
Today's Date: 4-23-2020
Title   ISBN    Quantity On Hand
____________________________________________________________________```
````

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  Please edit your post with the text results of your debugging session.  Include the actual and expected values of variables, as well as the input you used to trigger the issue.

Comment: Please edit **your post** with the text declaration for `book` class.  If your class has pointers, you can't use `read` or `write` methods for the entire class; you'll have to use a *serialization* method.  Pointers to your data don't survive well, because the OS can relocate your program to different areas in memory or locate your program's memory in different areas.

Comment: Ok is it good now?

Comment: Please post the declaration for the `BookData` class.  Sorry, due to your naming conventions, I got confused between `bookData` (the variable) and `BookData` the class.

Comment: For better coding style, please refrain from using class, method and variable names that only differ by case.  You could call the file `bookDataFile` for example.

Comment: `while(!bookData.eof()){` Nooooooo! Check the result of your actual read operation instead.

Comment: how do I do that?